# Getting ASP.NEt function to work with Ajax to fill a DropDown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webmethod

I'm trying to use a shared function and an Ajax with WebMethod to fill ans asp.net DropDown. I have tested the function in the page while the DropDown in an UpdatePanel using button on click and worked.

```
Public Function Update()

    Dim objDB As New DB

    Dim drProducts As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    objDB.Conn.Open()
    drProducts = objDB.cmdGetProducts.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Do While drProducts.Read
        DDLProducts.Items.Add(New ListItem(drProducts.Item("Title"), drProducts.Item("ProductID")))
    Loop
    drProducts.Close()
    objDB.Conn.Close()

End Function


Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Update()
End Sub
```

When I try to do it using the Ajax I get "Cannot refer to an instance member" in the Web Method if shared function and It doesn't work if public function

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function UpdateList()

    Try
        Update()
        Return "Success"

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "failure"
    End Try

End Function
```

And here is a jQuery script fires when a dialog closed

```
    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#MyDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Save": function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: '/AddProduct.aspx/UpdateList',
                            async: false,
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("some problem in saving data");
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {

                }
            });

            $("#name").click(function () { $("#MyDialog").dialog("open"); });
        });
    </script>
```

Any Ideas how can I fill the list elements with an Ajax and if it possible to reference to a control in a WebMethod - which I think it's not possible - and if there is a work around?

## Update

I have tried [this solution](http://forums.asp.net/t/1958662.aspx?How+to+bind+drop+down+list+dynamically+using+ajax+without+page+load) but couldn't get it to work with my code and can't know where is the problem

Comment: Update `Public Shared Function UpdateList() As String` . Since you are returning Something you have to add the return parameter

Answer (score 0):

Make the ajax call to this function directly `url: '/AddProduct.aspx/Update'`

```
Public Function Update() As String

   Dim objDB As New DB

   Dim drProducts As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
   Try
      objDB.Conn.Open()
      drProducts = objDB.cmdGetProducts.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
      Do While drProducts.Read
          DDLProducts.Items.Add(New ListItem(drProducts.Item("Title"), drProducts.Item("ProductID")))
      Loop
      drProducts.Close()
      objDB.Conn.Close()
      Return "Success"

   Catch ex As Exception
       Return "failure"
   End Try
 End Function
```

**AJAX**

```
                   $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/AddProduct.aspx/Update',
                        async: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("Record saved successfully in database");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("some problem in saving data");
                        }
                    });
```

**For Update Button**

```
 Protected Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim result As String = Update()
    If(result = "failure") Then
     'Show some kind of error
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and Thanks Ani, With Update as Public Function Update() can't include Update() in the method .. as Shared Function, I had to reference DDLProducts As New DropDownList and It doesn't work with both Ajax or UpdatePanel button.

Comment: I only want it to work the Ajax and the button is only for test

Comment: You can make Update As protected and make UpdateList public.

Comment: Also, if you are making `Function Update()` As function I think you have return something.

Comment: Thanks for your effort again .. I have tried your 3 advices in comments and answer  update.. all are working fine with the button and not with the Ajax. I even copied the Ajax code again but alerting the error status.

Comment: I have to say that the Ajax function has been called and worked before when I just included an SQL connection to update a field in DB for testing but not with trying to bind data to DropDown

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48625/discussion-between-ani-and-hsobhy)

Comment: the jQuery alert (some problem in saving data)

Comment: Your `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`,is json ...remove that line

Comment: fine, The Update() function do bind data and it's getting called and filling the list when call from button in UpdatePanel using onClick. but when I call it direct from ajax or even through UpdateList() method the Ajax alerts the error function.

Comment: Check my updated answer. You don't have to call `UpdateList` in button. You have to call `Update` everywhere. UpdateList won't work, because Update it already returning string...Check my update answer complete

Comment: Yes  removing the contentType returns the sucess stat but without filling the list. should I try all the advices again after removing the line?

Comment: No, Only button is working .. I even added an ajax function away from the dialog fires when body is clicked and doesn't fill the list but returns success

Comment: I really appropriate your effort. will try again all your comments tricks.